# How can we change value of a field in the Repeating Table using SharePoint Workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have an InfoPath form published on a SharePoint Library. The form contains a Repeating table and after submit a workflow runs. In this workflow I want to change some values of the fields within Repeating table.

How can I do this?

Thanks.